# how do you put php into HTML5

Tags: php, html, web

I just want to know how to put PHP into HTML5 ?

Comment: `<h1><?php echo $someVar ?></h1>`

Comment: `<header><title><?php echo   'Google increased the Title length.' ?></title></header>`

Comment: Also don't forget to save the file as .php if you are using php in html

Comment: You don't put PHP into anything. PHP is a scripting language, and it can output whatever it wants. If you want it to output HTML5, just do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First name you file to `index.php` instead if `index.html`
then you can write php wherever you want in that file..

```
<html>
    <?php
       write your php code here
    ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use contractions as < ?=$variable?> inside html. 
There is no any difference of using php tags between html versions

Answer (score 0):

First you need Web server.
You can embed php code in whatever place you want inside html document,  to make it run it should be delimited with `<?php  your_php_code  ?>` and save document with .php extension.